# Is there a way to obtain production environment variables from Heroku?

Tags: heroku, flask, heroku-cli

I'm trying to run heroku locally through the `heroku local` command. However, this doesn't use the environment variables in `heroku config`.

When I run `heroku local` I would like my local server to use the same environment variables found in `heroku config`.

I would like my local server to mimic the real world server; thats' why I'm trying to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of environment variables is that they're environment-specific. In many cases it doesn't make much sense to use the same ones in development as in production (e.g. your development database should probably be different from your production one, and you probably don't really want to send email in development).

In any case, `heroku local` supports loading environment variables from a `.env` file. You can [create a local `.env` file from your production environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file):

> Sometimes you may want to use the same config var in both local and Heroku environments. For each config var that you want to add to your `.env` file, use the following command:
>
> ```
> heroku config:get CONFIG-VAR-NAME -s  >> .env
> ```
>
> Do not commit the `.env` file to source control. It should only be used for local configuration. Update your `.gitignore` file to exclude the `.env` file.
>
> Keep in mind that your deployed production app may be connecting to different services than your local development app. For example, your deployed production app might have a `DATABASE_URL` config var that references a Heroku Postgres database, but your local app might have a `DATABASE_URL` variable in the `.env` file that references your local installation of Postgres.

Comment: The main issue with this is that Heroku rotates the API keys every so often. So, it would be pretty inconvenient to have to run that command every so often.

Comment: @echo, I'm not sure which API keys Heroku would rotate that you'd need to use in development. But this is the officially recommended approach and for what it's worth I think it's a good one. Feel free to read through the entire linked page for more background and reasoning.

Comment: The API keys are access to a database. The databases that Heroku themselves provide all claim to rotate their keys.

Comment: Okay, but why are you connecting to a Heroku database on your development machine? You should (almost) certainly be using a dedicated development database. Imaging making a mistake on your development machine and nuking your production database. And there are *lots* of other really good reasons to use a separate database for development (for schema changes and to have a smal set of local, curated data are two off the top of my head).

Comment: @echo, did this answer your question? Are you still planning to connect to your production database from your development machine, or have you decided to use a local one?

Comment: Yeah, I actually decided to use a different database provider that doesn't rotate the API keys. Thanks for the response though.